# No email communication after accepting a formal written offer. How should I phrase the call?

Tags: communication, job-offer, united-kingdom, conflict

*Background info*: So I was offered an position in a very small company (<50) in UK. The letter was in an email with the letterhead and the signature from the guy who interviewed me and I think he runs the company (maybe his father owns it). They were really excited to have me and the same was true for my side. The letter had details like salary, no. of holidays, working hours. Only condition I see is

> "This position is offered subject to satisfactory reference and pre-employment checks and completion of the three-month probationary period"*.

Initially I accepted by replying to email and asked to postpone the start date by a month. He was fine with it. But now I need to postpone it by two more weeks because I need to apply for a working visa before I can start. Haven't heard back after this email which was a week ago.

I'm guessing it's no longer on the table. But what annoys me is that he would lie and/or ignore me, rather than just saying no from the start because I stopped looking after accepting.

---

Anyways so what's the best way to phrase the call to him? I just want to know other's advice/experience on how this conversation should go/went.

Comment: You two never talked about the working visa? I think you might fail the _pre-employment checks_.

Comment: @scaaahu We did talk about it during the interview. He said they'll sponsor me. The second delay is because I need to graduate before I can apply, and starting date is before official graduation.

Comment: Did you tell him these details before? In particular, what did you tell him the start date would be in the first place? Did you think about the graduation date when you told him when you can start?

Comment: @scaaahu I told him I will start ASAP after I finish university. I didn't have set date then because they were not set. I didn't know I would need my grades to apply for visa. And now I need to wait for them to come through. But yeah, it wasn't clear, I guess I should have tried to.

Comment: You need to explain to him all those details you said above. Tell him the truth. Offer apology. You may still have the job. (You're young, immature. He might forgive you.)

Comment: And don't bet on the two weeks you'll need for the processing the working visa. You never know how long it will take. Tell him the truth. Tell him you will report to work the day you get the working visa. Be honest and up front.

Comment: @scaaahu Thanks! I'll try my best. Here goes nothing :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call and speak with the guy, ask to discuss the starting date, and explain the situation to him.

It might be that he's busy or he's forgotten your email, or he's so laid back, he's cool with it all.

Nothing really beats calling and having at least a short conversation so that you know what the deal is and get an idea how he feels about the delay - he might be perfectly ok with it, or he might want to negotiate, he might want you to start early regardless of the visa, he might want to reconsider and employ someone else.

Without talking, you won't know.